# My div #col its not aligning at center

Tags: html, css

Im trying to align my #col div at center of my container.
And Im trying to use marign:0 auto to do that, but I dont understand why my div is not aligning at center.
Somebody can help me figured it out?

Example with the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/V8NaR/2/

Html Im using for this example:

```
  <footer id="footer-container">
    <section id="footer">
         <div id="col" >
           <h1>Title of post</h1>
           <p>Post Content.</p>
         </div>
         <div id="col" >
           <h1>Title of Post 2</h1>
           <p>Post Content 2</p>
         </div>
    </section>
</footer>
```

Css:

```
#footer-container
{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    float:left; 
    background:gray;
} 


#footer
{
    width:480px;
    margin:10px auto 10px auto;
}

#col
{
    float:left;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    background:yellow;
    width:400px;
}

#col h1
{
    border-bottom:1px dashed #ccc;
    color:#fff; 
    font-size:17px;
    font-weight:bold; 
    margin-bottom:10px; 

}


#col p
{
    color:#fff;
    text-align:justify;
    color:#ccc; 
    font-size:15px; 
    margin-bottom:10px;
    text-align:justify;
}
```

Comment: IDs **must** be unique. Use classes instead.

Comment: You should follow all the advice about IDs given here. The problem is that you define `float:left` in the `#col`. Here is working version, a just remove the float and put a `margin: 0 auto;`: http://jsfiddle.net/V8NaR/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, avoid duplicating `id`'s - they must be unique.

The centering is off because the width of the `#col` elements is `400px`. The width of the parent element, `#footer`, should therefore be the same if you want the contents centered.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/92p6c/)

```
#footer {
    width:400px;
    margin:10px auto;
}
```

Also, the `#footer` element is collapsing upon itself because its children elements are being floated. You can solve this by adding a clearfix.

Either add `overflow:hidden` to the element:

```
#footer {
    width:400px;
    margin:10px auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

..or add a traditional clearfix.

```
#footer:after {
    content:'';
    display:table;
    clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, You shouldn't use the same ID more than once! Use classes instead

Second, in your CSS, I don't see any `margin: 0 auto`

Finally, your `#col` is floating to the left! It won't be centered!

remove the float property, and set the right margin property

```
#col{
   margin: 10px auto;
}
```

A fixed working example : http://jsfiddle.net/V8NaR/3/

Answer (score 1):

this will do it:

```
#footer-container
{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background:gray;
} 


#footer
{
    display: inline-block;
}
```